# Ubuntu server LVM mapper problem at boot when plugged a second hard drive

Tags: boot, lvm

I installed ubuntu 14.04LTS server version. Recently, I just successfully installed a second hard drive to use as glusterfs. But after a reboot, the server stop at loading stage with the error message:

```
ALERT! /dev/mapper/qtdev00--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
(initramfs)
```

I unplugged the second hard drive and it boots fine. Seems to me like LVM problem since another machine without LVM works perfect fine!

thanks for your help

Comment: I would suggest undoing the changes that you did, and make the changes one at a time. To see what specific thing breaks the system. And when you find out, maybe update this question with a more specifics.

Comment: HI Jmunsch, thanks for your reply. I edit up my question since the problem seems to be related with LVM after plugging in second hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! The problem had something to do with how long it takes for the controller hardware to actually respond back with the correct devices. With a delay,

```
edit the file "/etc/default/grub"
change from: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootdelay=90 nomodeset"
```

Reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877789&page=2

thanks